# CWAC-Camera now forces landscape

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I made a prototype of a video recording app using CWAC-Camera version 0.4.2 a while back and I was able to record in portrait mode.

I'm now moving forward with the project and upgraded to the latest version 0.6.3 and if the device is not in landscape it throws an UnsupportedOperationException: Video recording supported only in landscape.

I'd like to use the library but don't want to force the user to landscape for recording. Do I have to implement my own CameraView? I can't seem to find any comments on why landscape is required.

Any guidance would be great.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't seem to find any comments on why landscape is required.

Because, AFAIK, [portrait recording never worked](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues/130). It certainly never worked when I tried it -- the recordings all came out landscape.

There is [an outstanding issue to restore portrait recording](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues/133), doing something on devices where the video comes out wrong. I expect to address that in the 0.7.0 timeframe. In the meantime, drop back to 0.6.2, where IIRC portrait recording, with all its flaws, was still allowed.